# Is drawing through the Canvas class hardware accelerated on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, hardware, 2d

Are calls to Canvas.drawPath()/drawArc()/etc hardware accelerated, passed
to a device native implementation or implemented in Java?

Or is OpenGL the only way to achieve hardware accelerated drawing?

I am trying to determine if it is feasible to use the Canvas API for
realtime animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently Canvas is not hardware accelerated.

there are hints in the source code which point to the plans of implementing wrapping canvas calls around so HW accelerator, but it's not functional as of now.