# What is the native application API for iphone and android that is equivalent html5 canvas?

Tags: iphone, android, html, canvas

I have developed html5 canvas based animations (non-interacive) which work very well in latest desktop browsers but perform miserably on iphone and android. I want to port these web based html5 canvas application to native iphone and android applications. I am looking for something that will provide the quickest way to port such applications to native iphone and android applications without having to learn something completely different like opengl es. Is there such native API ( something like canvas 2d drawing surface) and if so what is the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the iPhone, you should look into [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_framework/_index.html) and [Animation Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html). I have 0 Android experience though, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Both of these API's for iphone and android are radically different from html5 canvas api requiring complete rewrite of the application. So the conclusion is that the answer to my question unfortunately is negative.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you have a [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). You can elect to use that alongside the existing widget set (e.g., by creating your own `View` subclass and overriding `onDraw()` to get the `Canvas` for the `View`), if you wish.

Note that I have not played much with the `Canvas` API, as graphics are not my strong suit, so I don't have all the details of how to use it for you.

Comment: According to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243347/is-drawing-through-the-canvas-class-hardware-accelerated-on-android) Canvas is not hardware accelerated. Has any one developed Android Canvas native application and what was the performance difference between the native and web based version?

Comment: Also I am the waiting for the iphone part of my question.

Comment: @Alan McCloud: "According to this post (stackoverflow.com/questions/1243347/…) Canvas is not hardware accelerated." -- correct. " Has any one developed Android Canvas native application and what was the performance difference between the native and web based version?" -- "anyone" won't answer unless you ask a fresh question. Use comments for follow-ups with the author of the answer.